# Store names linked with a "cooldown" timer in PHP

Tags: php

I'm planning to make a script with a little game in PHP and was curious how to have a way to store the users "name" linked with a timer acting as "cooldown".

I.E the script will be called with `url.com/script.php?username=XYZ` and I want to set a cooldown per user so whenever user1 has called the script, a cooldown of 30 seconds will be applied so user1 can't call it again until the "cooldown" has run out.

How can I do that without the use of a MySQL database?

Comment: Session or cookie I guess. Cookies can be accessed by JavaScript. But you should add some code because this is still way too broad

Comment: its planned to access the game via IRC chat. the bot will make an api call. im not sure cookies would work :c

Comment: Have the bot contain the cooldown. Maintain a list of users who are accessing the bot, and if the user calls the game within 30 seconds, respond with something like "Sorry, you can't do that yet".

Comment: `$_SESSION["cooldown_userid"]`?

Comment: it might work with the $_SESSION["ID"]. have to look into that. thanks for mention it!